# How to add a collection_select in a form within another form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I want to add a collection_select from a form I want to be within another form.

I have a Product model, with:

```
has_many :distribution_companies
has_many :distributors, :through => :distribution_companies, :source => :company
```

and Company model, with:

```
has_many :distribution_companies
has_many :distributed_products, :through => :distribution_companies, :source => :product
```

(The distribution_companies has only the references to the mentioned models)

This is the form (don't pay attention on the indentation):

```
= form_for @product, html: { :multipart => true } do |f|
= f.label :name do
  Name
= f.text_field :name

/.../

= f.fields_for :distribution_companies do |pn|
= pn.collection_select :company_id, Company.all, :id, :name

= f.submit 'Create the product'
```

I need to add select a company for the @product and store that in the distribution_companies table. I tried as abowe (also with pn.object.coll...). Any idea?

Comment: May be you are missing `accepts_nested_attributes_for :distribution_companies` in your `Product` model.

Comment: Can you post the `log` generated when you `submit` the form

Comment: Did you try adding what i suggested?

Comment: @Pavan `accepts_nested_attributes_for :distribution_companies` is already in the Product model. Nothing shows on the form (no drop down list) so, there's nothing to see in the log about it.

Comment: Atleast there would be some parameters generated.Can you post it in the question please.

Comment: Can you post your controller,may be you are missing `@product.distribution_companies.build`in the new method.

Comment: try `f.fields_for :distribution_company do |pn|`

Comment: @nithin OP has `has_many` relation.So your suggestion won't work.

Comment: @DR_ `DistributionCompany` model?

Comment: @Pavan thanks, I forgot the initialization: `@product.distribution_companies.build`

Comment: I will be adding it as answer,please accept it by ticking the tick mark green :)

Comment: @Pavan If I had any rep points, you would get even a vote up :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i said ,you have to add **`@product.distribution_companies.build`** to the **`new`** method of our controller.

```
def new
  @product = Product.new
  @product.distribution_companies.build
end
```